# Silverlight application. How to catch cntrl+N when browser catch this combination

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0

I need control+n key combination inside my application but browser responses on this command. How to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the question here, it might help

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/85402/220411.aspx